# Received :org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException

Tags: spring, jpa, jboss

I am making a JPA application in eclipse.I have designed the service layer with spring.I have 
used "HibernatePersistence" as persistence provider.
Below is my persistence layer:

```
    @MappedSuperclass
    public class BaseEntity implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2265881632984808864L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name="ID",nullable=false,updatable=false)
   private Long id;
   /**
   * @return the id
   */
   public Long getId() {
    return id;
    }
   /**
    * @param id the id to set
   */
   public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
 }

package com.edfx.jpapp.persist.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer", schema = "customerdb")
public class Customer extends BaseEntity {

/**
 * 
 */
@Transient
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1443119926544372161L;

@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
private String customerName;
@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ADDRESS", nullable = false, length = 25)
private String customerAddress;

/**
 * @return the customerName
 */
public String getCustomerName() {
    return customerName;
}

/**
 * @param customerName
 *            the customerName to set
 */
public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
    this.customerName = customerName;
}

/**
 * @return the customerAddress
 */
public String getCustomerAddress() {
    return customerAddress;
}

/**
 * @param customerAddress
 *            the customerAddress to set
 */
public void setCustomerAddress(String customerAddress) {
    this.customerAddress = customerAddress;
}

/**
 * @return the serialversionuid
 */
public static long getSerialversionuid() {
    return serialVersionUID;
}
  }
```

here is my DAO layer

```
package com.edfx.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import com.edfx.jpapp.dao.CustomerDAO;
import com.edfx.jpapp.persist.entity.Customer;

public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {

 @PersistenceContext(unitName="customerUnit")
  private EntityManager entityManager;

/**
 * @return the entityManager
 */
  public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
  }

/**
 * @param entityManager
 *            the entityManager to set
  */
  public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }

  @Override
  public void insertCustomer(Customer customer) {
    entityManager.persist(customer);
   }

   @Override
   public List<Customer> getAllCustomer() {

    return entityManager.createQuery("select c from customer c",
            Customer.class).getResultList();
    }
    }


 here is the service layer

package com.edfx.jpapp.service.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.dozer.Mapper;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.edfx.jpapp.dto.CustomerDTO;
import com.edfx.jpapp.persist.entity.Customer;
import com.edfx.jpapp.service.CustomerService;
import com.edfx.jpapp.service.base.BaseService;

 @Transactional
 public class CustomerServiceImpl extends BaseService implements CustomerService {

@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = { Throwable.class })
@Override
public void insertCustomer(CustomerDTO customerDTO) {
    Customer customer = getBeanMapper().map(customerDTO, Customer.class);
    getDaoProvider().getCustomerDAO().insertCustomer(customer);
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
public List<CustomerDTO> getAllCustomer() {
    Mapper mapper = getBeanMapper();
    ArrayList<CustomerDTO> customerDTOs = new ArrayList<CustomerDTO>();
    List<Customer> customers = getDaoProvider().getCustomerDAO()
            .getAllCustomer();
    for (Customer customer : customers) {
        CustomerDTO customerDTO = mapper.map(customer, CustomerDTO.class);
        customerDTOs.add(customerDTO);
    }
    return customerDTOs;
}
 }
```

I have placed my persistence.xml file under META-INF Folder: and it is as follows

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="customerUnit"
    transaction-type="JTA">
     <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
     <jta-data-source>java:/jBossCustomerMysql</jta-data-source>
     <class>com.edfx.jpapp.persist.entity.Customer</class>
     <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
     <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
     </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
```

I have used JTA DataSource and I have configured the JNDI in jboss standalone.xml file 
  as follows:

```
         <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jBossCustomerMysql" pool-name="jBossCustomerMysql" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customerdb</connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>root</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                </validation>
                <statement>
                    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
```

well when I ran the application my Tables got created in database.But when I try to insert a customer from xhtml page then I got the exception::

```
13:52:37,227 SEVERE [javax.faces.event] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8087-2) Received 'org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException' when invoking action  listener '#{customerController.addCustomer}' for component 'j_idt9'
13:52:37,227 SEVERE [javax.faces.event] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8087-2) org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
 at  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:427)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:329)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.insertCustomer(Unknown Source)
at com.edfx.jpapp.web.controller.CustomerController.addCustomer(CustomerController.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
```

Below is my spring configuration file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

 <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="customerUnit" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.edfx.jpapp.persist.entity" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

anther one is transactionConfig.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

 <bean id="transactionInterceptor" abstract="true"
     class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
    <bean           class="org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource" />
      </property>
      </bean>

     <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
       <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
     </bean>
  </beans>
```

can anyone give any solution to this??????

Comment: You get a NPE (nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException). Is there a part in your stacktrace that Shows where the NPE comes from?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.I need to add the following piece of code to my persistence.xml file.

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
```